# How can I play music using a speaker and Micro SD card Module?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to play music using my Arduino and micro SD card module but can't seem to do it. Can anyone shed some light on this? The SD card module I'm using is a Catalex sainsmart micro SD card module. It has the outputs `VCC`, `GND`, `MISO`, `MOSI`, `CS`, and `SCK`. `VCC` is in `5v`, `GND` is in `GND`, `CS` is in `Pin 4`, `MISO` is in `Pin 12`, and `MOSI` is in `Pin 11`.

Comment: Your question is very broad and more detail is needed. For example, I take it that the music file resides on the SD card but what format would the music be? Would you be willing to change format? Also, what is your circuit? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't care what kind of file it must be. Also CS is plugged into 4, SCK is plugged into 13, Mosi is plugged into 11, Miso is plugged into 12, VCC is plugged into 5v, and GND is in GND.

Comment: please edit your question and add these details. Comments are for information that can be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This Arduino project is one of the most simple and fun projects you
>   can build with Arduino in 10-15 minutes. The result of this make will
>   be an Arduino Audio Player which will play “.wav” files. It consist of
>   a speaker, a simple transistor acting as an amplifier and a micro-SD
>   card adapter with a micro-SD in it through which the .wav files are
>   loaded and played.

https://diyhacking.com/arduino-audio-player/

Comment: Thank you but does the speaker have to be the one he is using or can it be one that just plays clicks?

Comment: I expect any speaker is fine as long as the power is catered for, You can probably just wire a Piezo Speaker directly to output pins to play clicks

Answer (score 0):

Use an MP3 shield. This includes an SD card reader on the board. Many tutorials are available for this popular board. This shield makes it easier to program the Arduino.

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12660